# getting invalid hook call in react native useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to post the data from axios but I am getting invalid hook call error. What I am doing wrong here.
Here's my code

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const onLoginSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = baseUrl + '/';
    const loginData = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    setIsLoading(true);
    useEffect(async () => {
      await axios
        .post(`${url}users/login`, loginData)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);

          AsyncStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data.token));

          props.navigation.navigate('MainHome');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(error.res.data);
          setLoading(false);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    });
  };
```

Comment: It's unclear why you even need to use a hook here? Why not just make the Ajax call without it?

Comment: I did, but it was not working then, thats why i used useEffect

Comment: And then it still didn't work. I don't see any reason for useEffect here.

Comment: Can u pls edit my code then??

Comment: No. If the Ajax call didn't work without the useEffect, it's still not going to work. You need to post a new question with relevant information, but this time [ask about the actual problem and not the assumed solution](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 3):

You must call hooks on top-level, see [Rules Of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, **or nested functions**.

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const url = baseUrl + "/";
      const loginData = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      };

      await axios
        .post(`${url}users/login`, loginData)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);

          AsyncStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res.data.token));

          props.navigation.navigate("MainHome");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(error.res.data);
          setLoading(false);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    };
    if (loading) {
      fetch();
    }
  }, [loading, email, password]);

  const onLoginSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
  };
};
```

Comment: ok but I have to pass my state of email and password u can see on onLoginSubmit function, it is now showing that it's value is never read. How to solve it ?

Comment: Just move it to `useEffect` scope, I've updated the example

Comment: it is not giving any response, but It is working fine when I am using class component but I wanted to convert my code to functional component. btw thanks man for your time

Comment: Suggestion: in this screen i assume the user would login by clicking a button (user interaction) after filling the form (user/password) - so `useEffect` (which is for fetching data i.e) isn't necessary here at all.